# How to Upload files or image from PC with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, upload, cypress

I using Cypress , I have a form as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzMp0.png)
When clicking on it, I will open a window form to select files to Upload.
So, How to I select a file and upload with this window form ?
I tried with these cases in : https://github.com/javieraviles/cypress-upload-file-post-form
But it's not worked.

Thanks

Comment: The link to your image is not working, please edit your question. Thanks!

Comment: You can look it on this link : https://www.screencast.com/t/NgCdiwAeAFr

Comment: Still not displaying any image...

Comment: Sorry , I don't know the reason. It work for me, So, You can ignore it , I just want to upload a file or image from window form by Cypress such as:
Click on Upload button -> Have a window form -> select a file from computer and upload it

Answer (score 1):

I was at meetup with Gleb Bahmutov (VP of Cypress) and someone was asking him about file uploads/downloads in Cypress. He said that they are working on it, but it is gonna be out like in next two months.

I hope it is going to be in version `3.2.0` or `3.3.0`

Comment: Thanks for your information. Hope it is implemented in next version

Comment: Please check this thread, if it helps - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170